# Is my app or its dependencies violating the Android Advertising Id policy?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-advertising-id

I've just received this message from Google Play but I'm not collecting the Advertising ID.

> Reason for warning: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID
>   policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement
>
> Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when
>   the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information.
>   We’ve identified that your app collects and transmits the Android
>   advertising ID, which is subject to a privacy policy requirement.

Is it possible any of my dependencies uses it? Here's the list of dependencies:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$anko_version"

implementation ("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$android_support_version") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
}
implementation ("com.android.support:design:$android_support_version") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
}
implementation ("com.android.support:cardview-v7:$android_support_version") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
}
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.3'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.7.0'
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:$firestore_version") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-auth'
}
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$firebase_version") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-firestore'
}
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$firebase_version") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-firestore'
}
implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-firestore'
}
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation ("com.android.support:exifinterface:$android_support_version") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
}
implementation 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
```

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9gqr6y/anybody_know_which_sdk_violates_the_google_play/

Comment: I've added a privacy policy using https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: how did you confirm that you successfully stopped the violation after putting generated url?

Comment: Idemdito here. I filed a complaint, hope it will work... my app are my core source of revenue

Comment: Adding only privacy URL does not  work they removed my app again on 2nd day after providing privacy URL we need to make code changes i believe still figuring out what code fix is needed

Comment: Was there any latest update in compliant with google policy since your release?

Google often update their privacy policy and notify developer every time new policy released. You probably ignored that in your developer console.

Comment: I think thank google can hide applications but not remove them, I read this email only now 25 September at night, notifications were 7 days ago. I must now resubmit all my apps at night. I think they are not normal.

Comment: I have the same issue, How did you fix it?

Comment: In my case the problem is FirebaseAnalytics . I removed it and submitted a new build. Do I need to provide privacy policy ? or it will be published again? @WouterVandenputte

Comment: My app got kicked, I added a policy online... Got kicked again. I added a policy to the app itself... Got kicked again. Changed the policy to one from firebase specifically... Got kicked again. Changed the policy in app and online and filed a complaint... Went back up but there no follow up so I'm unsure why it was taken down. I like so many others here was only using firebase analytics. Game was in Unity3D. Not using any ads in the game. for reference, the game is https://lexicube.app

Answer (score 72):

### Disable advertising id collection

According to the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics) you can disable advertising id collection by setting:

```
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` under the `<Application>` tag.

EDIT: It seems like people are having mixed success with this approach.  Try adding 
`configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core' all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-iid' }` to the Gradle app dependencies area as per comment below.

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, how many ad libraries (and other fodder) did this crash because they assumed `AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo()` would always succeed?

Comment: This will not crash any other Ad libraries. It will only notify firebase to not collect the ad id. I am only using firebase messaging still firebase is collecting analytics and other stuff by default and I can see this on the console.

Comment: Just a question: if you do this the ads in your app will no longer be relevant to the user interests, right?

Comment: I *think* it only disables the collection of the id for analytics. The ads themselves will still be relevant.

Comment: I used this technique and my app got reinstated without submitting any privacy policy.

Comment: so nice of google to kick my app out of the store with no warning for using firebase, way to go google

Comment: It's not the solution. In my case I added this line and republish. After some days, my app was kick out again from google play.

Comment: Well, I added this to my manifest and the app was republished, only to be unpublished a couple of weeks later for the same violation.  I don't use Firebase or crash analytics - its' a pretty lean app.  Hopefully this was just an error on their part.  I bumped up the version number and added:
  configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-iid'
    }
to the Gradle app dependencies area.  Hopefully that will do the trick.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how long it takes for them to put the app back up after putting out a new release?

Comment: This solution doesn't work:
1) the syntax of exlcuding dependencies should be:
```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-iid'
}
```
2) if dependencies are excluded and app tries to configure for example firebase messaging, then app crashes with NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Got my app reinstated without needing to add configurations or a policy statement. Took about 24 hours.

Comment: Is this one needed aswell (coming from the Firebase docs)?     
`<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="true" />`

Comment: It's so silly that two part of google is not sync with each other and developer should pay that's cost!

Answer (score 58):

Today many developers are getting this same issue. 
I also got this issue. I didn't collect any sensitive data, I am not even showing ads to my users. ***In your case the Crashlytics lib could be an issue***. It deals with advertising IDs.
In the mail they mention the required action:

> ***Action required***: Add a privacy policy to your store listing and app

So I think all of us should add a privacy policy on the store listing as well as on the app. Before taking the action we should go through the related privacy policy.
Here are some links from where you can get help:

[Privacy policy to upload an app](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#privacy)

[Usage of Android Advertising ID](https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/ads/ad-id/)

[Developer Distribution Agreement](https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_us/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html)

[Developer Program Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/#!?modal_active=none)

Comment: ...or don't use Crashlytics, or any other dependency that may be violating people's privacy. I believe this is now illegal in Europe anyway, and the fines are potentially huge. If you use services that may be siphoning away people's private data, to which the id belongs, you put them (and your company) at risk.

Comment: @Cerberus Using them is certainly not illegal, but you need to collect opt-in and fulfil additional requirements. Good on Google for enforcing this, actually (though they probably don’t do it out of the goodness of their heart).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Should "meeting the minimum legal requirements" be the standard against which we decide if privacy is violated?

Comment: @Juggerbot It’s unclear whether Google has any legal requirement in this regard; they probably do it to cover their asses just in case but the infringing party in this case according to GDPR would be the app developer, not Google.

Comment: Apple announced that from 3rd October every app owner have to add privacy policy. But our android!!!??? OMG

Comment: GDPR is a privacy ruling. It has nothing to do with anonymous data collection, [unless those identifiers can be combined or resolved to identify a natural person (recital 30)](http://ec.europa.eu/justice/data-protection/reform/files/regulation_oj_en.pdf). Since that is arguably the case for the advertising ID, hence the requirement for a privacy policy and consent. Since Crashlytics no longer uses it, *you do not need a GDPR consent dialog to use Crashlytics, so long as you update to version 2.9.3 or later.*

Answer (score 22):

You are using crashlytics below 2.9.3. Apparently it's collecting and sending the google advertising id as a key in their header. That might be the or one of the issues. 
You can check if it's sending the advertising id through a proxy like Charles.

Edit ***
It seems that version 2.9.3 and above are still getting the advertisingID from by calling `AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo()` from the `com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier` package. I checked it by setting a break point on the method. I am assuming it is somehow still being send to fabric. Which would mean updating to higher version will not solve it..

Comment: How do you check?

Comment: @RikvanVelzen You mention version 2.9.3. Can you point to the info saying that in newer versions it is is not an issue?

Comment: @Yossi: no the only thing i can point to is the reddit post which link you can find in to comments of the question. And I checked myself through Charles that in 2.9.3 the X-CRASHLYTICS-ADVERTISING-TOKEN is not sent in the header anymore.

Comment: Crashlytics does not send Advertising ID starting from 2.9.3. Mike from Fabric stated clearly: "From Crashlytics SDK version 2.9.3 and higher, we no longer submit the Android Ad Id to our servers. In prior versions of the Crashlytics SDK, this Id was primarily collected and submitted for Mobile App Conversion Tracking and Audience Insights (both of which are now deprecated features)." (https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9gqr6y/anybody_know_which_sdk_violates_the_google_play/e67i5iw)

Answer (score 20):

For Unity users, the problem is in **Unity Analytics**.

To resolve this problem, we need to do **2 tasks**:

- In **Google Play Console**, add the link: **https://unity3d.com/legal/privacy-policy** into **Privacy Policy** field in **Store presence / Store listing**
- In your app, add a **Privacy Policy** button by using the Unity's own plugin **Unity Data Privacy Plug-in**: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/add-ons/services/unity-data-privacy-plug-in-118922

After resubmitted about some minutes, Google Play approved my app.

Comment: In Unity 2018, can we remove the package of Unity Analytics and Ads to fix this too?

Comment: @GabrielStafoca I think that it is possible, you can try it

Comment: Not if you're actually _using_ the Analytics... ;)

Comment: @GabrielStafoca that worked for me. I also added unity's privacy policy URL on store listing. Btw I wasn't using Unity Ads or Analytics. https://unity3d.com/legal/privacy-policy

Comment: @QuangTran you sure this will solve it in unity? the emails from google state..Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

Comment: @DavidMarsh I received this email from Google Play, because I published my game that using Unity engine to Google Play. They said that: my app collects and transmits the Android advertising identifier, which is subject to a privacy policy requirement. I don't collect these infos but Unity Analytic did.

Comment: The Data Privacy plug-in is part of the Unity Analytics Library package in 2018.3+ https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityAnalyticsDataPrivacy.html

Answer (score 16):

I am not using Crashlytics or any other thing. Just a simple offline app with Facebook Ads. Still my app was removed from the Play Store.

**Issue:** Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

**Issue Description:** Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information. We’ve identified that your app collects and transmits the Android advertising identifier, which is subject to a privacy policy requirement. If your app collects the Android advertising ID, you must provide a valid privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Console, and from within the app.

**Solution:**

1. I created a Privacy Policy for my app using this [link](https://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/free-privacy-policy-generator.php) and edited it according to my app.
2. I created a url for my privacy policy using this [link.](https://sites.google.com/)
3. Log in to [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) and Go to the Store presence and then store listing and paste your url in Privacy Policy section.
4. Submit your update.

**Note -** In my case **I did not have to submit any new build** with privacy policy as mentioned in mail and my app was visible in play store within hours I did the steps I mentioned above. If in case your app is not visible in play store after following the above points then you should put one privacy policy section in your app too and submit a new build.

Comment: That's exactly the solution, I just had this problem last night, and I wrote a Privacy Policy and added the link to console, and now it's published again.

Comment: Were downloads affected after the app was brought back?

Comment: No. The downloads were same.

Comment: Was your android app removed or you were given a warning?

Comment: The app was removed but it came back once I put the privacy policy as explained in the answer.

Comment: https://play.google.com/about/enforcement/policy-coverage/ did this work on this too? I got the mail for this POLICY COVERAGE and I don't know how to solve this issue. My App is still live but not getting updating even not screenshot I can.

Answer (score 14):

I also recieved the same message and got some of my apps suspended today.

So i just deleted those three firebase dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
```

Then, i re-submitted the apps, and they was accepted after review :)

Comment: resubmitted app now it is visible in play  app store?

Comment: Yep, they are accepted en ligne again on Play Store.

Comment: This is the only answer so far that shows how to _stop collecting the information_!

Comment: What if my app is showing ads? Since you removed firebase-ads dependecy

Comment: Firebase is just for tracking users interactions and analytics

Comment: I was using FirebaseAnalytics. Removed FirebaseAnalytics completely and resubmitted. But the app was removed again. Any idea why? @Gama

Comment: If I will remove the firebase-ads sdk then how will I show the admob ads in my app now?

Answer (score 7):

If your app uses Firebase SDKs like analytics and all, you can disable  `Advertising ID` collection on SDK level by putting the following line in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file under the `Application` tag.

`<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />`

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics).

My app was not even an ad supported application but still it got hit by this `section 4.8` clause. By employing the above technique I was able to get it back on Google Play **without submitting any privacy policy**.

Comment: I am not using firebase SDK but I am using Fabric so is it okay if i only add privacy policy section in my app and provide url in my console ?

Answer (score 6):

this is the cause
Google Play Services version 4.0 introduced new APIs and an ID for use by advertising and analytics providers.
We need to provide a privacy statement and make it available on the web.
For a sample go 
https://digital.com/blog/best-privacy-policy-generators/

To change settings on your android app. Developer Console, Store Listing, scroll down to Privacy Policy. Add the url here.

Comment: How do you know it has to do with GPS 4.0+? How is that connected to the advertising ID violation?

Comment: I did, but it's quite unclear if and how google play services uses the advertisingID and if there is a way to disable or opt-out of it. Are you 100% sure it's due to GPS 4.0+ and could you pinpoint to where the advertising ID is used/transmitted?

Comment: as the text reads "Google Play Services version 4.0 introduced new APIs and an ID for use by advertising and analytics providers". I use crashlytics to collect crash details, admob (free version app) and Fabric to collect statistics so if any of these apply then you are apparantly transmitting an adversingId.

Comment: Is it necessary that privacy policy URL should be a dedicated  website? OR can we use some type of free blog  for this purpose like blogger.com?

Answer (score 6):

## copied from google mail

**Please contact policy support team.**

1. If your app requests user data or makes sensitive permissions requests such as Phone, Accounts, Contacts, Camera, Microphone, or if your app uses the Android advertising identifier, you'll need to add a valid privacy policy in two places: your app's Store Listing page (instructions below) and within your app.
2. As a second option, you can remove any requests for user data or sensitive permissions. For example, you would need to remove {copy and paste permissions here} from the manifest. You will not need to add a privacy policy if you remove these requests.
   If you cannot complete steps 1 or 2, you'll need to unpublish the app from the Play Store.
3. If your app is already unpublished, you don’t need to take action unless you re-publish the app in the future.

**You can follow these steps to add a privacy policy to your Store Listing:**

1. Sign in to your Play Console.
2. Select your app.
3. On the left side, select Store presence > Store listing.
4. Under "Privacy Policy," enter the URL where you have the privacy policy hosted online.
5. Save your changes to submit the update to your app.

Please visit our [help center](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#privacy) for more information about Google Play privacy policy requirements.

[image]

Comment: means no need update the apk?or  just privacy url is enough?

Answer (score 6):

Disabling Advertising ID collection:

https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics#disable_advertising_id_collection

via those two lines in Manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="true" />

<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

Answer (score 3):

my app deleted from store today .. same issue 
all i do that i add privacy policy to the app from(App console - Store presence - Store listing)
[Like the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV0KN.png)
you can create it from [App Privacy Policy Generator](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/#)
and uplaod it and write the link in Store listing and resubmit the app
That is work for me
and sorry for my bad language

Comment: how did you confirm that you successfully stopped the violation after putting generated url?

Comment: beware, you need to update your app as well, not just the link in Developer Console. From past experience, google do not notify that you are compliant. they will simply remove the app from the store again. I guess we just need to wait until the deadline has passed with crossed fingers.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Crashlytics and OneSignal. Relying on @RikvanVelzen tests with Crashlytics 2.9.3, it is not the reason for my getting the messasge from Google, but OneSignal.

Google requirement is "you must provide a valid privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Console, and from within the app."

Therefore, I believe that I need to do only two things which are not too complicated:

1. Add a privacy policy link from Google Play's console, to a webpage with the info
2. Add privacy policy info in the app

The following seems to provide instructions on how to do it (just one of many):
https://www.iubenda.com/blog/warning-google-play-developer-policy-violation-action-required-policy-issue/

Answer (score 3):

**Privacy policy webpage creation:**

- First, create a page with the privacy policy of the blocked
  application.
- Write what information you process. If you do not process private data, write it clearly.
- Add information (link) about app privacy policy in Google Play Console

**App update with consent:**

- Follow the instruction from Google website: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent
- Add link to your privacy policy:
  `privacyUrl = new URL("https://www.your.com/privacyurl");
  ConsentForm form = new ConsentForm.Builder(context, privacyUrl)`
- Add the privacy policy webpage by opening it in browser or in webview in your application
- Update app with consent and upload on Google Play Console

Comment: is this applicable for non admob user?

Comment: you need adMob account to select ad technology providers: "Sign in to your AdMob account and select ad technology providers.", see: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7666519#providers

Answer (score 3):

I had one of my app removed and another got warning for reason given as 
Issue: **Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement**

I created the privacy policies for both the apps, updated the link in play console store listing, included privacy policy link in main menu of both apps and resubmitted apps.
Both the apps are now live and running .
If you need you can copy the policy, make sure to do edits according to your app permissions and name.
[Privacy policy](https://beautifulappss.wordpress.com/2018/03/18/privacy-policy-2/)

I don't know if these play console removal and warning count as strike, or somebody can enlighten me.

Comment: Is not a strike, you get strike if you app is in "Suspended" status if you can upload again app, is not strike, is strike when you can´t upload again app.

Comment: can you please tell me that Is it necessary that privacy policy URL should be a dedicated  website? OR can we use some type of free blog  for this purpose like blogger.com?

Comment: @NoamanAkram As you can see i have used word press blog site, so it can be any url a s long it is public and works. You check the mail they have mentioned the points for url.

Comment: thanks @user2983041 one of my app was removed ,obviously its not same as suspended so as i understood it is not counted as strike , right? What about update rejected for any policy violation, will it be counted or not ?

Answer (score 3):

step 1 : add privacy and policy url to play store console

step 2 : create a button example in side bar when button clicked just call this below method and add your url here

```
private void callThisMethodWhenPrivacyButtonClicked() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Title here");

        WebView wv = new WebView(this);
        wv.loadUrl("{your privacy and policy uurl }");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }
        });

        alert.setView(wv);
        alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to create a privacy policy URL and then add this URL in *GOOGLE PUBLISHER CONSOLE* based on application.
You can easily create privacy policy using this website.

[Privacy Policies](https://privacypolicies.com/)

If you have a server/host try to upload privacy policy page on your own server otherwise you can use this website for storing.

**Mentioned**: you have to add this policy page on your application. Create a menu as privacy police and show all your policy content on a dialog. Easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

I received a warning from Google recently mentioning that I have violated the Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.

I dont use ads on my app , but I am tracking users events / analytics using **Amplitude** and **Fabric** , which might be the cause of this warning.

**Action required to solve the problem:**

1. Generate privacy policy using [Firebase app privacy policy generator](http://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com.)
2. Include your generated privacy policy into your app , and make it accessible to users.
3. Update the app, and add privacy policy link (via Web page, or Google doc) to your store listing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue states the violation is due to using user's Android Advertising ID. I had the same problem. I created a privacy policy and added the url to that in my app and to the Google Play page. Submitted an update and the App is live again. Make sure to mention that you are collecting a personally identifiable information, Android Advertising ID, in your app. I've given a link to my app's privacy policy, refer to that if you need to know how exactly it is mentioned.

This is my privacy policy:

https://nwsty.com/privacy-policy-and-terms-of-use-android/

You can easily create a privacy policy here:

https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/

[image]

Just for reference, this is the app in question:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instancea.nwsty&hl=en_US

Answer (score 0):

I got 3 apps suspended today.
I had a busy day but managed to start working on the apps after lunch. I worked on and submitted 2 updates out of 3. Now I'm working on the third one.

A few minutes ago, one just got approved.
Most of my apps already have privacy policies. The ones that got suspended did not.
The suspect libraries in my case are Admob and Firebase Analytics.

What I did:
1. I created a privacy policy web-page and added a link in the Google Play Store listing.
2. I added the privacy policy as a string in the app and it pops up via a dialog the user can accept or decline one time.

After the updates, I held my breath for 2 hours and voila!

Comment: can you please share some code that will help us to make similar changes in everyone app  how to add the privacy policy as a string in the app and it pops up via a dialog the user can accept or decline one time.

Comment: That might be a silly question but what are you doing in case the user declines the privacy policy by clicking the "Decline" button?

Comment: Same thing that happens when you decline an EULA