# React Native: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

Tags: google-play, react-native, policy

I got this policy in my `React Native App` :

#### Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

form **Google Play**

I use this dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "lodash": "^4.17.10",
  "react": "16.3.1",
  "react-native": "0.55.3",
  "react-native-device-info": "^0.21.5",
  "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
  "react-native-google-analytics-bridge": "^5.8.0",
  "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.6",
  "react-native-map-clustering": "^1.3.0",
  "react-native-maps": "*",
  "react-native-masked-text": "^1.7.2",
  "react-native-onesignal": "^3.2.5",
  "react-native-svg": "^7.0.3",
  "react-native-ui-kitten": "^3.0.1",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
  "react-navigation": "^2.0.2",
  "victory-native": "^30.4.0"
},
```

Comment: Might be something related to device info to get user information without opting in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disable advertising id collection

According to the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics) you can disable advertising id collection by setting:

Add this `meta-data` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` under the `<Application>` tag

```
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

And add `configurations` in your `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-iid'
    }
    repositories {
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}
```

resource : [Is my app or its dependencies violating the Android Advertising Id policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52380615/is-my-app-or-its-dependencies-violating-the-android-advertising-id-policy/52393188#52393188)

Answer (score 1):

I think you use these dependencies: react-native-device-info, react-native-google-analytics-bridge, they cause your problem, you must provide url policy on your app for google

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create a valid privacy policy document

You can generate it easily here using [this](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/) tool.

And then

1. We have to place a privacy policy link within the app. You can create the same as a text link anywhere in the app menu. It should be opened in the external browser on click.
2. Then you have to place the same link in the Play Store. Go to Play Store `console -> Store presence -> Store listing`. Go to the last field named ‘Privacy Policy’ and update the link there.
3. Submit app update and Store listing update together.

Your app will be back online within 2 hours!