# How do I know what package is trasmitting the Android advertising ID? (App removed from playstore)

Tags: android, google-play, data-protection

Good afternoon everyone,

Yesterday I've received a message from Google Play Store stating that my app was removed from app the app store due to:

> Issue: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement
>
> Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information. We’ve identified that your app collects and transmits the Android advertising identifier, which is subject to a privacy policy requirement. If your app collects the Android advertising ID, you must provide a valid privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Console, and from within the app.
>
> Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information. We’ve identified that your app collects and transmits the Android advertising identifier, which is subject to a privacy policy requirement. If your app collects the Android advertising ID, you must provide a valid privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Console, and from within the app.
>
> Next steps: Submit your app for another review
>
> Read through the Usage of Android Advertising ID and User Data policies, as well as the Developer Distribution Agreement, and make appropriate changes to your app. If you decide to collect sensitive user information, be sure to abide by the above policies, and include a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's store listing page and within your app. 
>   Make sure that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies. Additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy violations.
>   Sign in to your Play Console and submit the update to your app.
>   Alternatively, you may opt-out of this requirement by removing any requests for sensitive permissions or user data.

The thing is we already cover data protection in the terms and conditions that must be accepted in order for the user to log in.

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0'
compile project(':tracker')
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.1.5'
compile 'edu.vt.middleware:vt-password:3.1.2'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
```

}

Any thoughts?
Thanks very much in advance

Comment: this may help https://medium.com/@swarooptvm/how-to-fix-advertising-id-policy-violation-in-google-play-store-6d9cf92d335d . Had same issue in an app even though there were no ads....saw another post that this might have also been triggered by app asking for certain permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is my app or its dependencies violating the Android Advertising Id policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52380615/is-my-app-or-its-dependencies-violating-the-android-advertising-id-policy)

Comment: If you already have terms and conditions put them on the web in the form of a privacy policy and add it to your play store listing.  Then you won't get this.

Comment: Thanks very much I´ve already seen that link but posted the question anyway since I already have a privacy policy. I think that the problem is not having the privacy policy in a public url and listed in the play store.

Comment: Thanks also @GabeSechan and Markus Kauppinen. You replied at the same time I was answering John :)